# Доступ к переменной дочернего класса

Tags: java

Всем привет, сегодня столкнулся с вопросом о наследовании.
Вот суть:

```
abstract class Class1{
    int method(){
        //тут хочу возвращать счетчик 'a' с класса Class2
    }
}
```

```
public class Class2 extends Class1{
    int a;
    void method2(){
        a++;
    }
}
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

Спасибо.

Comment: Либо ваш счетчик является базовой функциональностью, и, следовательно, определен в абстрактном классе, либо никак.

Answer (score 5):

Если добавить в прототипе метода первого класса аргумент в качестве объекта дочернего класса, а потом передавать его таким образом:

```
Class2 cl = new Class2();
System.out.println(cl.method(cl));
```

Сам метод первого класса должен быть объявлен таким образом:

```
abstract class Class1{
    int method(Class2 ob){
       return ob.a;
    }
}
```

А иначе никак. В разумном понимании этого слова. Абстрактный класс создан для того чтобы ограничить возможность создания объектов его типа. Следовательно он может восприниматься в качестве интерфейса для дочерних классов. Для начала почитайте вот это http://kostin.ws/java/java-abstract-and-interfaces.html И я уверен что у вашей задачи есть более разумное решение.

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь нарушить один из негласных принципов программирования: классы ничего не должны знать о сових потомках. Едва ли не единственное исключение из этого - абстрактный класс, который тоже не имеет права напрямую обращаться к потомкам. Однако вы можете хакнуть систему (и тут я повторно предупреждаю о том, что это неправильно) и сделать абстрактный геттер для `a`:

```
abstract public getA();
```

В этом случае класс-родитель сможет получить `a`, вызвав этот метод.